# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, types, number-formatting

I'm trying to convert a String timestamp to an Integer one and I'm using postgres as DB.

```
@Column(name = "connecte_timestamp")
private Integer timestamp;

SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
Date aujourdhui = new Date();
this.timestamp = Integer.parseInt(formater.format(aujourdhui)
                .replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").replace(":", ""));
```

the timestamp have `bigint` as a [type](http://docs.postgresqlfr.org/8.1/datatype.html#datatype-numeric) in the DB.
When I run my app, I get the following stack trace :

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "01092013062024"
>     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.forum.beans.Connecte.(Connecte.java:26)     at
>   com.forum.servlets.ListageForums.doGet(ListageForums.java:32)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Any help please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1092013062024 is too big for `int` use `long` instead. I would also do it a little differently

```
private Long timestamp;

SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
timestamp = Long.parseLong(formater.format(new Date));
```

I think yyyyMMddhhmmss format is more logical, it makes comparison and sorting simple